# Multiple SurfaceView: multiple threads?

Tags: android, multithreading

Should I use one thread for all SurfaceViews, or is it fine to use one thread per view? I would say the secondo option is rather simpler, but I do not know if it would have some performance or memory problem.

Comment: I am interested in this as well. I currently have two SurfaceViews with one thread for each one. Almost certainly this approach consumes more battery.

Comment: I have many surfaces and many threads is not good IMHO. The app lags when creating them. Moreover, I had some problems while scrolling in a scrollview.

Comment: It is possible to control two SurfaceViews with one thread. I think you need to pass in the SurfaceViews to the thread as delegates, and the thread should call the draw() method on each one.

Comment: I know, yet it is more complicated to control multiple surface views (which are updated on a timout) in a single thread. On the other hand for now I think I will just leave this complicated stuff and do things simpler.